# What's the 3rd argument of monkeyrunner.press

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

After SDK tool upgrade to revision 12, When I connect to monkeyrunner and use press method like device.press('KEYCODE_HOME','DOWN') 
Will get error msg

Traceback(most recent call last):
 File "", line 1, in 
TypeError:press:The 3rd argument is required.

But I checkde sdk doc that press only contain two argument. is it problem caused by new version SDK tool.

Comment: I see the same error. And checking the sources it seems indeed that only 2 are required. Very strange.

Comment: Looks like a bug in monkeyrunner. Just add a blank String as a third argument, and it'll work.

Answer (score 3):

To press a key using monkey runner you need to use something like `device.press('KEYCODE_HOME',MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)` you shouldn't need to add a 3rd argument.

Perhaps your issue was that you were using `'DOWN'` instead of `MonkeyDevice.DOWN`

Comment: got the same problem, at 2.3.3

Comment: Take a look at the monkeyrunner device source code at http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/sdk.git;a=blob;f=monkeyrunner/src/com/android/monkeyrunner/MonkeyDevice.java based on what I can tell it seems to say that press only needs 2 arguments. But perhaps it might be helpful to find whats wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the third argument is also a string indicating the press type. It is a constant in `MonkeyDevice`: `DOWN`, `UP` and `DOWN_AND_UP`

If you do not want to import `MonkeyDevice` to only use it on this, the correct string which would be used in Monkeyrunner should be `'down'`, `'up'` and `'downAndUp'`.

They are defined in enum class `ChimpChat.TouchPressType`. Here below is its partial source code:

```
public enum TouchPressType {
    DOWN("down"), UP("up"), DOWN_AND_UP("downAndUp");
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To press a key using monkey runner you need to use something like device.press('KEYCODE_HOME','DOWN',' ') you didn't get the any error.

The 3rd argument will be blank here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add MonkeyDevice

For example a paste command would look like this.

```
device.press('KEYCODE_PASTE',MonkeyDevice.DOWN)
```